# How do you find the natural logarithm of a complex number (not using the Euler or polar forms)

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that a complex number is represented as "a+bi", in the rectangular form.

Now, in case I wanna take a logarithm (ln) on this complex number, it is necessary to convert it into Euler form before doing further.

Is there any other way to evaluate the logarithm of a complex number, without changing it into an **Euler or Exponential form?**

Comment: Does this [DLMF 4.6(i) logarithm series](https://dlmf.nist.gov/4.6) page answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just use the formula $$\operatorname{Log}_k(z) = \log |z| + i(\arg z+2\pi k),$$
where $\operatorname{Log}_k:\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is (one branch of) the complex logarithm, $\log: (0,\infty)\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the usual (i.e. real) logarithm, $|z| = |a+bi| = \sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, and $\arg z$ is the angle between the real axis and $z$ (measured *counter*clockwise). Also, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ is a fixed integer, since increasing the argument of complex number by an integer-multiple of $2\pi$ results in the same number: $$z = |z|\cdot e^{i\arg z} = |z|\cdot e^{i\arg z}\cdot 1 = |z|\cdot e^{i\arg z}\cdot e^{i2\pi k} = |z|\cdot e^{i(\arg z + 2\pi k)}$$

Now the only question is how you compute the argument. This is not entirely trivial, since neither of the trigonometric functions $\sin,\cos,\tan$ is bijective - i.e. you have to first convince yourself, which specific inverse function is to be chosen to calculate the $\arg z$.

For example, $\cos: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow [0,1]$ is only bijective on an interval of maximal length $\pi$, e.g. $[0,\pi]$. Thus, the formula $$\arg z = \arccos \frac{a}{|z|}$$ is only valid if $\operatorname{Im} z = b\geq 0$ (i.e. if $z$ lies above the real axis). If $z$ lies below the real axis, this formula becomes $$\arg z = \pi+\arccos\frac{a}{|z|}. $$